# Eyelid thickness variation

Tags: eye, eyelids

I am working on a project in which I have to measure inter ocular pressure (IOP) of the eye. Currently, the gold standard to measure IOP is using goldmann applanation tonometer, in which anesthesia is being used as there is corneal contact with the sensing probe.

I am working on to measure the IOP with the closed eyelid. Using probe for sensing. I am not getting consistent value of the IOP. The design I am working on consist of applying small pressure to the eyelid and eye and then measuring the reaction from it.

Does eyelid of all people are consistent or there is variation in it. I have considering average eyelid thickness of 2 mm[Schutte, van den Bedem, van Keulen et al. (2006);Ljubimova (2009)]. 
Is this assumption good enough to do the analysis.